# SQL replace int in string by text

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a query but in my result I have a column with the number '2' which I want to be replaced by 'factura'.

How can I do this?? I want to replace Cust.[Document Type] column

```
   SELECT Detail.[Entry No_],
           'Cliente' AS Tipo,
           Cust.[Customer No_] AS Cliente,
           Detail.[Posting Date] AS DATA,
           Detail.[Document No_] AS Documento,
           Detail.[Amount (LCY)] AS Valor,
           Cust.[Document Type] AS LiqPorTipo,
           Cust.[Document No_] AS LiqPorNDocumento,
           '97' AS Conta,
           'MR' AS Loja,
           'SUPER' AS Utilizador,
           'MR01' AS POS
    FROM dbo.MBS_tabela_21Detailed_NAV16 AS Detail
    INNER JOIN dbo.MBS_tabela_21_NAV16 AS Cust ON Detail.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_] = Cust.[Entry No_]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Integracao_Periodo_NAV16 AS Integr ON YEAR(Detail.[Posting Date]) = Integr.Ano
    AND MONTH(Detail.[Posting Date]) = Integr.Mes
    WHERE (Detail.[Document No_] LIKE '%REC%'
           OR Detail.[Document No_] LIKE '%L%')
      AND (Detail.[Entry Type] = 2)
      AND (Cust.[Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'LMR')
```

this results in

```
359229  Cliente 503392154   2018-03-23 00:00:00.000 1803PAGLEITE37  -2064,62000000000000000000  2   MRVFFT1800012   97  MR  SUPER   MR01
```

and i want to have

```
359229  Cliente 503392154   2018-03-23 00:00:00.000 1803PAGLEITE37  -2064,62000000000000000000  fatura  MRVFFT1800012   97  MR  SUPER   MR01
```

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: What sql platform are you using?  What is the error message, if any, returned?

Comment: Error in FROM clause: near 'SELECT'.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: And which SQL server do you use?

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: Where does fatura come from? Please eloborate on the logic a little.

Comment: I have in column Cust.[Document Type] the number 2 (by running the previous query) and I want to show factura because the number 2 means factura understand?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is missing "Detail.[Entry Type] column". Comparing expected query result and your query result I assume you would like to use either case or create dictionary table to join it.

Best option would be to create additional table and store there all key-value translations.

So you could have 
2 - factura

And join it in your query.

If not you should do like this:

```
 SELECT Detail.[Entry No_],
           'Cliente' AS Tipo,
           Cust.[Customer No_] AS Cliente,
           Detail.[Posting Date] AS DATA,
           Detail.[Document No_] AS Documento,
           Detail.[Amount (LCY)] AS Valor,
           case when Cust.[Document Type] = 2 then 'factura' else '' end  AS LiqPorTipo,
           Cust.[Document No_] AS LiqPorNDocumento,
           '97' AS Conta,
           'MR' AS Loja,
           'SUPER' AS Utilizador,
           'MR01' AS POS
    FROM dbo.MBS_tabela_21Detailed_NAV16 AS Detail
    INNER JOIN dbo.MBS_tabela_21_NAV16 AS Cust ON Detail.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_] = Cust.[Entry No_]
    INNER JOIN dbo.Integracao_Periodo_NAV16 AS Integr ON YEAR(Detail.[Posting Date]) = Integr.Ano
    AND MONTH(Detail.[Posting Date]) = Integr.Mes
    WHERE (Detail.[Document No_] LIKE '%REC%'
           OR Detail.[Document No_] LIKE '%L%')
      AND (Detail.[Entry Type] = 2)
      AND (Cust.[Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'LMR')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to replace one column base on join result. Bellow [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server) may help you

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

Base on above structure your sql scritp is bellow.

```
UPDATE Detail
SET Detail.[Entry Type] = REPLACE(Detail.[Entry Type], '2', 'factura')

FROM dbo.MBS_tabela_21Detailed_NAV16 AS Detail
INNER JOIN dbo.MBS_tabela_21_NAV16 AS Cust
  ON Detail.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_] = Cust.[Entry No_]
INNER JOIN dbo.Integracao_Periodo_NAV16 AS Integr
  ON YEAR(Detail.[Posting Date]) = Integr.Ano
  AND MONTH(Detail.[Posting Date]) = Integr.Mes

WHERE (Detail.[Document No_] LIKE '%REC%'
OR Detail.[Document No_] LIKE '%L%')
AND (Detail.[Entry Type] = 2)
AND (Cust.[Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'LMR')
```

Comment: Assuming the data type isn't `INT`.

Comment: After join you have value and you know the destination column type, So you can cast it.

Comment: This isnt working... Column or expression 'Document Type' cannot be updated.
This SQL statement type cannot be used in a view or function.
Only a SELECT statement can be used.

Comment: I alter the Update table for Cust and the Set field to Cust.[Document Type]

Comment: What is your document type?  What type of data you want to store in this column. Please check hope types are not mis-match